# How to set the text to Label element on data on entering new Scence ? I am using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Actually i am working on small project for my college. I am using mySQl server from XAMPP. I have build login system for that using Java FX. I want to add some data from my database to the Label Element using controller class after succesfull login.

This is my Controller i've used in the Scence builer.

```
package LoggedIn;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Controller {
    @FXML 
    public static Label username;

    @FXML
    protected void getUserData() {
        System.out.println(username.getText());
    }    
}
```

Here's my FXML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: pink;" stylesheets="@login.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="LoggedIn.Controller">
<children>
<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="147.0" style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;Resources/sliderBack.jpg&quot;); -fx-background-size: cover;">
<children>
<HBox prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="147.0">
<children>
<ImageView fitHeight="28.0" fitWidth="24.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
<image>
<Image url="@../Resources/loginIcon.png" />
</image>
<HBox.margin>
<Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
</HBox.margin>
</ImageView>
<Label fx:id="LabelUsername" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="86.0" styleClass="txt" text="Welcome" textFill="#e50e99">
<HBox.margin>
<Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="15.0" />
</HBox.margin>
<font>
<Font size="15.0" />
</font>
</Label>
</children>
</HBox>
<Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="Settings">
<VBox.margin>
<Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
</VBox.margin>
</Button>
<Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="Posts">
<VBox.margin>
<Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
</VBox.margin>
</Button>
<Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="Ask Question">
<VBox.margin>
<Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
</VBox.margin>
</Button>
<Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="Rules">
<VBox.margin>
<Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
</VBox.margin>
</Button>
</children>
</VBox>
<VBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="454.0" style="-fx-background-color: #a8dbbf;">
<children>
<VBox prefHeight="154.0" prefWidth="452.0" style="-fx-border-color: green; -fx-border-radius: 3;">
<VBox.margin>
<Insets bottom="0.5" left="0.5" right="0.5" top="0.5" />
</VBox.margin>
<children>
<Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="430.0" text="User Details" textFill="#e12828">
<VBox.margin>
<Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" />
</VBox.margin>
<font>
<Font size="20.0" />
</font>
</Label>
<HBox prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="430.0">
<VBox.margin>
<Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" top="-10.0" />
</VBox.margin>
<children>
<Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="179.0" text="Username :">
<HBox.margin>
<Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
</HBox.margin>
<font>
<Font size="15.0" />
</font>
</Label>
<Label fx:id="username" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" 
prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="303.0" text="Bhusal1">
<HBox.margin>
<Insets left="10.0" />
</HBox.margin>
<font>
<Font size="15.0" />
</font>
</Label>
</children>
</HBox>
<HBox prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="430.0">
<children>
<Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="165.0" text="Email :">
<HBox.margin>
<Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
</HBox.margin>
<font>
<Font size="15.0" />
</font>
</Label>
<Label fx:id="email" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="303.0" text="asdasdasdasd@gmail.com">
<HBox.margin>
<Insets left="10.0" />
</HBox.margin>
<font>
<Font size="15.0" />
</font>
</Label>
</children>
<VBox.margin>
<Insets left="10.0" />
</VBox.margin>
</HBox>
<HBox prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="430.0">
<children>
<Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="162.0" text="Verification :">
<HBox.margin>
<Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
</HBox.margin>
<font>
<Font size="15.0" />
</font>
</Label>
<Label fx:id="verStatus" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="303.0" text="Verified">
<HBox.margin>
<Insets left="10.0" />
</HBox.margin>
<font>
<Font size="15.0" />
</font>
</Label>
</children>
<VBox.margin>
<Insets left="10.0" />
</VBox.margin>
</HBox>
</children>
</VBox>
</children>
</VBox>
</children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong with something. I'm new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you're doing right now is you have a label, with fx:id `username` which has nothing in it. Your `getUserData()` method gets the text of that label (which is probably the empty string `""`, or `null`), and prints it to the console.

In order to actually change the Label, you need to call `setText` on your `username` label, and give it a String. Where and how you get the String from your database is up to you.

**Edit**:
You mentioned changing the label "on entering new Scence" (sic). I'm not sure what you mean by that, but in any case, there's a certain order that is followed when a Controller instance is created from FXML.

First, the controller's instance variables are created (those NOT annotated with `@FXML`)
Second, the controller's Constructor is called, if it exists
Third, the `@FXML` elements are injected
Fourth, an `initialize` method is called, if it exists

So, if you want to change the text of `username` when the fxml is loaded, your best bet would be something like this:

```
@FXML
public void initialize(){
    // TODO: get your username from SQL or whatever
    String name = "surya bhusal";
    username.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: Actually i don't want to set text after clicking the button. It must happen after entering the new Scence. I've called a method from the main Class. But also null Pointer Exception.